# DAX Measure Top N with others in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure, top-n

I'm developing a report in Power BI where i need to show the Top N Countries by the value of some Produkts they produce.

I already managed it to calculate the Top N countries which are variable, but I have no idea how to sum the "Others" in there.
 So i need e.g. the Top 5 plus "Others" in the stacked Bar Chart.
Unfortunately I can't add a measure in the legend field, so I need a workaround for that.

Comment: I found a solution for this here: https://blog.oraylis.de/2016/12/show-top-n-and-rest-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 4):

You have to add an "Other" country in your countries table, since you cannot add a country or group of countries dynamically.

First you have to create a rank measure.

```
Sales Rank=RANKX(ALL(Data[Country]),[Sales])
```

Use the rank measure to determine how to sum the measure you want to show.

```
Top3:=IF ([Sales Rank] <= 3,[Total],
  IF(HASONEVALUE(Data[Country]),
    IF(VALUES(Data[Country]) = "Others",
       SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Country] ), [Sales Rank] > 3 ), [Total] )
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38089892/2647648) I posted in other question.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work in Power BI because as i said I can't add a measure to the stacked bar Chart legend.
If you use Power BI check the 100% checked bar Chart, in the legend i divide the bar into the countries, but i can't dinamically add "Other" countries there. maybe Microsoft will provide a solution soon...