# How to write the DAX query for top n records and rest of the records should be others?

Tags: dax

```
How to write the DAX query for top n records and rest of records should be others?

Example:-

Table name sample

 col1     col2
 --------------
 a        10
 b        20
 c        30
 d        40
 e        50
 f        60

I need output like top 3 records rest of should be "others"
like
         col1        col2
        -------------------
          a           10
          b           20
          c           30
          others      150
        -------------------

     Can anyone please help on this. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38089892/2647648) I posted in a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be dynamic? if not you could do it the lazy way

```
evaluate ( 
summarize ( 
            sample,
            if(pathcontains("a|b|c", sample[col1]) = false(), 
                "others",
                sample[col1]
                ),
    "col2", sum(sample[col2])
            )
    )

order by 
sample[col1]
```