# How to combine 6 tables in one Matrix, show top 12 and categorize the rest as others?

Tags: sorting, if-statement, powerbi, dax

I need to be able to sum availability based on product and say show me top 3, and categorize the rest as Others. I have two tables in a matrix connected by a product table.

I tried so many ways -

i was able to create this measure for July (which is what i will be sorting with) - I get the correct ranking column for July.

i know i'm missing something. i tried to take that ranking measure statement and add an if statement and couldn't get it to do the ranking.

the picture would make more sense *(my formulas are based on actual column names)

```
Partner Ranking =
VAR summry =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLSELECTED ( Latest ),
        [partner_group],
        "Sum", COUNT ( Latest[site_url] )
    )
VAR tmp =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( summry, "RNK", RANKX ( summry, [Sum],, DESC, DENSE ) )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( tmp, [partner_group] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Latest[partner_group] ) ),
        [RNK]
    )
```

I don't know what to do next. how can i do this when i have a separate table that is the product name that links the two tables?[image]

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087699/power-bi-topn-and-all-other

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thank you :)