# Power BI Sankey with Slicers

Tags: powerbi, sankey-diagram

I have a Sankey diagram that I want to be in a certain order. I locked the aspect ratio when I clicked two of my slicers and for that particular combo, it goes back to my order but for other combos it doesnt.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have taken the labels off because this is for work. but below is what I want it to look like 
[image]

and you'll see that I selected Underrepresented Minority in the Ethnicity Categories and Female in the Gender one

Believe it or not it does make sense. then when I select something else, all the colors change and then so does the order of the flows. Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated. I tried locking it and changing the order of the source data and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a weight column to order it the way you'd like? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sorting-in-Sankey-Visual/td-p/366497

Comment: I've seen that suggestion, thank you. i'm already using a calculation for Top 5 as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087699/power-bi-topn-and-all-other and i can't use two weights. :-(

Comment: You should be able to use the "Top N" filter from the Filters pane and not have to use a measure for that.

Comment: Thank you I am aware of that feature but this calculation also puts the non-Top N into an "other" category so that feature can't be used either